Ubuntu appears to be lost network after VMWare move
I moved all the virtual machines folders to another hard drive then used scan virtual machine in VMWare to retrieve VMs fast but all the machines network interfaces are all off though they worked perfectly before moving. The network type is NAT.


I tried ip link set ens33 up and netplan apply but still not working.

Update: It turns out that I chose "I moved it" when the VM first booted up after moved that lost all the configurations. While the other VMs that option "I copied it" chosen works great now. But the problem still remains, can anyone help?

Try to remove the network interface of the VM (in vmware) > Apply changes > then add a new interface, and start from the beginning: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/configuring-networks
